# How to decrease the default number of Database in Redis ?

Tags: redis

The default number of Databases in Redis is 16. I know that we can change this using the redis.conf , whose location I checked using info-server command on redis-cli .
But When, I am trying to decrease it to 2, its not picking up the change, and , CONFIG GET databases , still gives me 16. 
So, what is the way to decrease the default number of databases in Redis ?

Comment: Basically, what I want is that , because we do not want to use multiple databases in Redis, and we have a huge data. So, let's say if 128 GB RAM is there in the system, our main database should have most of it available, and it doesn't gets distributed in 16 parts.

Comment: The memory is shared by all databases.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To change the number of databases:

1. edit `redis.conf`
2. change `databases` value to 14 (if you want to decrease by 2)
3. **restart redis service**, that depends on your operating system and Redis installation, for mine, Ubuntu, I have to run from command line `sudo systemctl restart redis`

So probably you forgot step 3, if you don't restart Redis service, configuration changes will be not available

Btw, AFAIK you don't distribute your database in 16 parts as you say, if you don't use from 1 to 15 databases, they won't use RAM, you just consume the RAM you need

*Update*

First of all, is very strange you cannot reduce the number of databases to 2, do you have already some data on databases from 2-15? (remember the first database is 0) Did you save redis.conf file after change `database` pram = 2? Are you sure you are using the right command to restart Redis service?

Regarding how to confirm redis reserves RAM for unused database, it is something you can deduce from the nature of `in-memory` redis is and taking a look simply in the definition of `select` command:

https://redis.io/commands/select

> Redis different selectable databases are a form of namespacing: all the databases are anyway persisted together in the same RDB / AOF file. However different databases can have keys having the same name,

So basically Redis uses a kinda of key namespaces which are added to the name of the key to difference keys belonging to different databases, and since Redis just put in memory data when they are saved there is no a previous reservation of memory for empty databases. Probably you are a little bit confusing with other databases manage memory or hard disk when you create a database

Anyway if you are worried about memory leaks, take a look at `maxmemory` and `maxmemory-policy` here is this article

http://oldblog.antirez.com/post/redis-as-LRU-cache.html

Also, if you are using Redis v4.0.0+ you can be interested in `memory doctor`
and `latency doctor` command but you will need some data in your Redis to get some useful info. You can also use this Python console tool to get key usage memory stats:

https://github.com/gamenet/redis-memory-analyzer

Other useful links to understand how Redis manages memory and operate:

https://redis.io/topics/faq

https://redis.io/topics/memory-optimization

Comment: I had tried to restarted the redis-server . But, the change doesn't takes place somehow. It still gives me 16 databases. Though, my intention was to make the total number of databases 2, so that Redis doesn't distribute my total available memory in 16 parts. That is because I want to use only 2 databases : one for configurations, and other for data. But, if Redis doesn't distribute my RAM in all its databases, then I think there is no need for this exercise. How can I confirm this fact ?

Comment: I extended my answer to respond your comment

Comment: Thanks Averias. This helps.

Comment: Your welcome @Prashant. Anyway if you consider that my answer is ok for you and clarified your questions, please mark it as ``accepted``. If not, and you are waiting for better answers please don't forget to accept the best answer you finally find. Regards